# Laravel firstOrNew by a specific table column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have an array of objects coming from the frontend. I only want to create a new record of what's coming in if not already present in the database but only by the `primaryKey` ('The_ID').

When I use `firstOrNew`, it creates duplicate entry.

Model:

```php
 protected $primaryKey = 'The_ID'; // Fake name.

 public $incrementing = true;

 public $timestamps = false;

 protected $fillable = [
   // all fields except the $primaryKey
 ];
```

Controller:

```php
 $array = $request->lists;

 foreach ($array as $list) {
   ( new Model )->firstOrNew([
     'sue' => 'young',
     'foo' => 'bar',

     'datetimeadded' => \Carbon::now() // previous dev used this name :(
   ])->save();
 }
```

What I'd like is that, if `The_ID` is in the database, do not save. `The_ID` comes in the request so I can access it with `$list['The_ID']` in the loop.

If this was already answered, please close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstOrNew` accepts 2 arrays. 1 is your `where` clause basically and the second is what you want to insert. By using only 1 array you basically have a where clause in everything. Modify you code to:

```
foreach ($array as $list) {
   ( new Model )->firstOrNew(
   ['id' => $request->id],
   [
     'sue' => 'young',
     'foo' => 'bar',

     'datetimeadded' => \Carbon::now() // previous dev used this name :(
   ])->save();
 }
```

The first array i used basically is something like:

```
where('id' ,'=',$request->id);
```

- **id**: the PK of your table,
- **$request->id** : id of an element coming from the front-end matching
  your PK.

You can also use `updateOrCreate` for that so you will update the current fields of an existing record or create a new record.

Comment: Thanks. Ive just found this https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Builder.php#L417

Comment: Cool, this is my answer basically just elaborated a bit more to it so it is more clear for future users as well !!!